# How do I fix "The type or namespace name could not be found"?

Tags: c#

This is a followup to my earlier question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/efficency-in-c/12169, and I tried my best to use BigIntegers in place of the ulongs, but I must have done something wrong.  I am new to C#, and I am familiar with Java.  This was my best shot at conversion:

```
using System;

namespace System.Numerics{

      public class Factorial{

             public static void Main(){

             String InString = Console.ReadLine();

             BigInteger num = 0;

             BigInteger factorial = 1;

             try {
                 num = BigInteger.Parse(InString);
                 Console.WriteLine(num);
                 }
             catch (FormatException) {

                  Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the String into a BigInteger");
            }



            for (BigInteger forBlockvar = num; forBlockvar > 1; forBlockvar--){

                     factorial *= forBlockvar;

            }

            Console.WriteLine("The Factorial for the Given input is:");

            Console.WriteLine(factorial);
    }
}
}
```

And I got the following errors:

```
prog.cs(11,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `BigInteger' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
prog.cs(13,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `BigInteger' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
prog.cs(26,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `BigInteger' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add a reference (right-click on References in the Solution Explorer and select Add Reference) to System.Numerics.dll.

Also, put in `using System.Numerics` rather than having your method's namespace be that (i.e. name it something more descriptive for your codebase).

Comment: Wait, I am having problems with my Mac's Installer, so i have not gotten MonoDevelop working yet... I am using ideone.com in the meantime...

Comment: @CodeAdmiral AFAIK ideone does not allow you to add assembly references.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add assembly references:

1. Go to References and Properties

[image]

2. Click the "Add..." button at the bottom of the new window. Click browse and find the .dll file relating to the namespace you want. For example my path is:

```
C:\My-Folder\My-Project-Name.ViewModel\bin\Debug\My-Project-Name.ViewModel.dll
```

3. Once I'd done this, I could add the relevant namespace in the "Additional Namespace Imports" tab:

[image]

Simply type the namespace on a new line in the textfield.