# Problem with using BigInteger type in C# code

Tags: c#, biginteger

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to write code for the Fibonacci sequence. I get an error when I use the BigInteger type in my code.
I would be grateful if you could help me solve this problem.

this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace FibonacciSequence
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int start = Environment.TickCount;
            BigInteger i1 = 1;
            BigInteger i2 = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(i1);
            int count = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (count++ % 100000 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i2);
                }
                BigInteger next = i1 + i2;
                i1 = i2;
                i2 = next;
            }
            int end = Environment.TickCount;
            Console.WriteLine(end - start);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error:

"The type or namespace name 'BigInteger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: What version of .net are you targetting?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850251/3744182) by Jesse C. Slicer to [How do I fix "The type or namespace name could not be found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10850250/3744182) also answer your question?  The solution there is to *add a reference (right-click on References in the Solution Explorer and select Add Reference) to `System.Numerics.dll`.*

Comment: @Neil .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: This code compiles: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gNW4uR

Comment: The code is correct, but I got the same error in FW4.8 & Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.4084.0 for C# 5. Looks strange.

Comment: Or if you are building via the command line rather than in Visual Studio (your question doesn't specify how you are building) does [Including library while accessing compiler via console interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11831106/3744182) answer your question?